# regexp_replace для greenplum (оставить несколько первых и несколько последних символов, остальное заменить *)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql

Прошу помощи в разборе регулярки по маскированию текста:
есть входной текст "my masking string"
хочу получить "my*************ng"

Подобрал выражение: select regexp_replace('my masking string', '(?<=..).(?=..)', '*', 'g');
но это выражение работает только для postgresql

greenplum показывает ошибку
'invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid'
опытным путем понял, что ошибку вызывают знак '?' в регулярке
пока не пойму чем его заменить, или как пересобрать выражение.

Comment: Наверное не понимает ретроспективнe. проверку '(?<=)`... А при замене функцию может использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обойтись встроенными функциями. И работать будет быстрее, чем с регулярками, если говорить про большой объем данных.

```
select substr('my masking string',1,2)
|| repeat('*',length('my masking string')-3)
|| substr('my masking string',length('my masking string')-1);
```